# Is it possible to use spacy rules based matching without defining the order, or the number of words between, the key words?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to match sentences in a document which contain (**both**) two key words ('fox' and 'dog') using spacy. My problem is that I don't want to always specify the order of the words, or number the words in-between the words of interest. I just want to match sentences where they both exist.
Is it possible to do this?

For example is it possible to write a rule that would match both sentence1 and sentence2, but not sentence3 or sentence4.

```
sentence1 = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

sentence2 = 'The quick fox is brown and jumps over the lazy dog.'

sentence3 = 'There is a fox in my back garden'

sentence4 = 'There is a dog in my back garden'
```

[A typical spacy matching rule looks like this:](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher)

`pattern = [{"LEMMA": "dog"}, {"LEMMA": "fox"}]`

Obviously this wouldn't work in my case though, as spacy would like for occurrences of dog and fox next to each other.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not understandable. Could you clarify it better? The code snippet does not seem to relate to any of the sentences and no application can be thought of.

Comment: hmm I've edited it now, is that better?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried split the sentences, and then check for words? In your example,

```py
list1 = sentence1.split()
list2 = sentence2.split()

count = 0
for word in list1:
    if word in list2:
        count += 1

print('Match words =', count)
```

If you want to count words just once, and you don't want to take capitals into account, then

```py
set1 = set(sentence1.lower().split())
set2 = set(sentence2.lower().split())

count = 0
for word in set1:
    if word in set2:
        count += 1

print('Match words =', count)
```

Comment: I would like to do it with a NLP package if possible, but thanks I'll consider what you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use this along with your code:

`{"OP":"|"}`